# Dead MSI 8800 GTS 640MB?

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-geforce, black-screen-of-death

My PC appears to boot fine, I can hear it get to Windows but I can't see anything on the screen. The screen is completely blank/black... no POST/BIOS/Windows etc. The problem only happens when my 8800 GTS is plugged into the screen (LCD). Using an alternative video-card or on-board video works completely fine.

Things I've tried:

- Different (brand new) motherboard
- Different PSU
- Many different H/W combinations (just in-case it was conflicting with something)
- Tested every stick of RAM individually
- Cleaned off the video-card's contacts (using a rubber) and all the dust on the fan
- Different DVI cable
- 2nd DVI slot on the card

Also, if I unplug the power connector from the PSU to the video-card it beeps. Plugging it back in stops the beeps.

I'm running out of ideas... is my card dead?

**Edit:** I have a sneaky suspicion that the primary DVI port might be the cause of the problem. Is there any way to force it to use the secondary DVI port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to test the card on a friend's system, although

> Using an alternative video-card or
>   on-board video works completely fine.on-board video works completely fine.

indicates the the card is most probably dead.

Comment: Will take the card into work tomorrow and try it there.